# Make a stoplight which changes colors every 2 seconds in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

My goal is to create:

1. A white screen, with a green light in the middle
2. In the redlight, contain a small light that can change color from white to red every 2 seconds
3. On the top left side, there's a button with text 'stop light', when user click the button, spotlight changing will stop.

My code:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

# def color
white = (255, 255, 255)
green  = (0, 255, 0)
red = (0, 0, 0)

# screen
screen_w = 640
screen_h = 480
screenSize = (screen_w, screen_h)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 400))
pygame.display.set_caption("white light and red light")

# create button
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
image = pygame.image.load('pngtree-vector-play-icon-png-image_924817.jpg')
screen.blit(image, (80, 440)) #how to add text next to the imgage?

# draw circles
pygame.draw.circle(screen, red, (320, 240), 240)
pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, (320, 240), 120)
pygame.draw.circle(screen, green, (320, 240), 120)


# 2 second color change rule
running = True
while running:

    clock.tick(2)
    
pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

I'm very new to programming so please bare with me with silly mistakes.

Comment: You should wrap any code blocks in triple backticks so it is more readable

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of colors and a variable that store the index of the current color:

```py
colors = [white, green, red]
current_index = 0
```

In pygame exists a timer event. Use [`pygame.time.set_timer()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) to repeatedly create a [`USEREVENT`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) in the event queue. The time has to be set in milliseconds. e.g.:

```py
timer_interval = 2000 # 2.0 seconds
timer_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(timer_event, timer_interval)
```

Note, in pygame customer events can be defined. Each event needs a unique id. The ids for the user events have to be between `pygame.USEREVENT` (24) and `pygame.NUMEVENTS` (32). In this case `pygame.USEREVENT+1` is the event id for the timer event.

Change the color index when the event occurs:

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == timer_event:
        current_index += 1
        if current_index >= len(colors):
            current_index = 0
```

Draw a circle with the current color in the application loop:

```py
while running:
    # [...]

    pygame.draw.circle(screen, colors[current_index], (150, 200), 120)
```

---

Complete example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

white = (255, 255, 255)
green  = (0, 255, 0)
red = (255, 0, 0)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 400))
pygame.display.set_caption("white light and red light")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

colors = [white, green, red]
current_index = 0

timer_interval = 2000 # 2.0 seconds
timer_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(timer_event, timer_interval)

running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == timer_event:#
            current_index += 1
            if current_index >= len(colors):
                current_index = 0

    screen.fill(0)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, colors[current_index], (150, 200), 120)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: thanks, but how can add an image as a button and when the user clicks the image, the spotlight will stop changing color? thanks

Comment: @evenevaa This is a new question. If you have a new question, [Ask a public question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)